# Loop through angularfire2 list

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, reactive-programming, rxjs, angularfire2

Assuming I need to get all items from an order of items.

- I need to get the item keys from the order
- Iterate over each item key and subscribe to each `.database.object` to get the item details.

---

```ts
 let myItems = [];
 let orderItems = this.af.database.list('/order_items');

 this.orderItems.subscribe((itemKeys) => {
   itemKeys.forEach((itemKey) => {
     let item = this.af.database.object('/items/'itemKey.$value);

     item.subscribe((itemData) => {
       myItems.push(itemData);
     });

   });
 });
```

This can be problematic since the `orderItems` subscription is not yet finished and the `forEach` is executed. Ofcourse I can check the list for duplicated later, but I'm pretty sure there is better way.

**My question** - Is there any better way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

I think you can get the data as the original snapshot by specifying the preserveSnapshot option as described here:
[Retrieving the snapshot](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/3-retrieving-data-as-lists.md#retrieving-the-snapshot)
and then iterate as you need.

```
let myItems = [];
let orderItems = this.af.database.list('/order_items',
  { preserveSnapshot: true }
);

this.orderItems.subscribe((itemKeys) => {
  itemKeys.forEach((itemKey) => {
    let item = this.af.database.object('/items/'+itemKey.key);

    item.subscribe((itemData) => {
      myItems.push(itemData);
    });
  });
})
```

I think you could also map the `items` with the keys to `order_items` right away, something like here: [AngularFire for Angular 2](https://youtu.be/ngnSOTSS8Q8?t=3998), but I am not sure how to do this, since I am new to ng2, af2 and firebase.

Comment: Not sure what `preserveSnapshot` does, but the problem remains  - and this is nothing to do with it. I think this problem comes because the observable stream is not good.